# tensorflow: propagate error to placeholder

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to propagate error to a placeholder? I need to fixed the params of the model and only propagate errors to the placeholder. The placeholder has mini-batched vectors and the batch size is unknown..

Edit:(use tf.gradient suggested by @Alexandre Passos)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


X = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, 100])
Z = tf.constant(list(range(100,200)), dtype='float')
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(X - Z))
grad = tf.gradients(cost, X)
appl = X - tf.multiply(grad[0], 1)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    x0   = np.random.normal(size=[2,100])
    for _ in range(500):
        x0,c = sess.run([appl, cost], feed_dict={X:x0})
        print(c)
    print(x0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `tf.gradients` lets you pass any `Tensor` you like as the variable to be differentiated.

Comment: I tried optimizer.compute_gradients(cost, var_list=[S_placeholder]) and it raises NotImplementedError: ('Trying to optimize unsupported type ', <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?, 500) dtype=float32>)..

Comment: Did you try `tf.gradients(cost, [S_placeholder])`? The optimizer assumes it's working with Variables as it will run Variable-specific ops in the apply_gradient method.